# How is the ending -ig pronounced, and where?

Tags: dialect, pronunciation

I've heard the following alternatives for pronouncing the ending *-ig* of words like *fertig* and *lustig*:

- /ɪç/ (as in *mich*)
- /ɪʃ/ (as in *Fisch*)
- /ɪg/
- /ɪk/

Where are the different pronunciations used? Are there more alternatives?

Comment: I think four are more than enough... ;)

Comment: This is a very good question. Many Germans are confused about it, too, even if they use the correct pronunciation.

Comment: As a not German native speaker, who has lived in southern Germany, I can attest I've heard all of the variations, so I guess nothing got solved here. Saludos desde México

Comment: I lived in Baden Wurtenberg, Hessen and have daily contacts with Munich (many workers, a mix of many regions and countries). I could hear “isch” in Hessen a lot, specially among “cool, girls who defied society standards”
But it was sporadic. I see in the above map that it’s prevalent in the Mainz, south-west of Frankfurt, all the way to the west.
Normally, g and k are well defined and there is no confusion. Sometimes people just make emphasis to stand out. I’m in my 50s and have lost touch of youth slangs.
The TV doesn’t reflect street accent trends or evolution. The words, “irgendwo” has a un

Answer (score 38):

This map, from a [collection of surveys](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/) done by the University of Augsburg, shows the distribution of the different pronunciations:
[Aussprache König, wenig und zwanzig](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-1/f14a-c/)

[image: How König is pronounciated in different regions]

Comment: The survey this map is based on was of course flawed because it did not  offer the option *König.* Since Southern German does not have final hardening («Auslautverhärtung»), we may assume that most of the *Könik* entries in this map really ought to be *König.*

Comment: I can't hear/imagine what the difference between König and Könik might sound like.

Comment: I pronounce it with something between a soft g and ch.

Answer (score 23):

There are regional differences.

In Austria and the southern areas of Germany, you will hear

Honig like "Honik"

König like "Könik"

When I took speech and drama lessons half a life time ago, it was pointed out that these words actually rhyme with "ich", so /ɪç/ is correct.

Honig is pronounced like "Honich"

König is pronounced like "Könich"

wenig is pronounced like "wenich", but of course it is a "g" sound in "weniger als ich dachte"

Comment: I thought that was a pronunciation exception for adjectives, but you seem to be right. I've always thought _König_ was pronounced -ig or -ik in standard German.

Comment: The "Fisch"-like ending is very typical for Saxony. Additionally the "i" can merge to an "ü" sound or get swallowed. ^^

Comment: And of course there are some regions where *weniger* is pronounced with something between /ç/ and some kind of /j/.

Comment: Sorry to say but I have never ever heard anybody in Austria or Bavaria using a emphasized k instead of a g. I know of north and easter germany the usage of 'ch' instead of g. Please be more specific about what regions are included (south is pretty big, and Baden-Wuerttemberg and Vorarlberg are using alemanic but are less than 1/3 of the south ...

Comment: I live in Austria for almost 50 years. I never heard "Honik" or "Könik". The last konsonant is pronounced as a "g", not a "k": Honig and König (spoken exactly as written). But to be precise: This is NOT a dialect-pronounciation! This is austrian standard german!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Actually the (Austrian) pronounciation lies somewhere in between. Same goes for p/b and t/d. Most notably that can be seen from the genuinely southern question "Mit hartem oder weichem [...]?". Try pronouncing either with a distinct /g/, and you will feel alienated by yourself. Still, "Könik" is obviously not an ample description.

Comment: I believe you are all confused by surface phonology in inflected forms. For me (north), the plural is definitely voiced with /g/, *Könige*, or regionally iotacized, *köinje*, something like that. Following the latter, it may be bracketed according to the maximal coda onset principle, *kö-ni-(g)e*, giving opportunity to rebracketed backformation *Köni'*, Genitiv *des Könixs* wenn bloß stimmlosig nicht regressiv assimiliert wird, etwa *des Köniks*. Umgestellt nach X folgt ganz richtig *der Könik*, wie *köniklich*, wobei \*K etymologisch ansatzweise gerechtfertig sei, vgl. *einem König gleich*.

Answer (score 7):

Noch eine kleine Ergänzung (mit Links zu mp3-Dateien) zu der Antwort von teylyn:

Laut *Duden Band 6 – Das Aussprachewörterbuch* spricht man in der deutschen Standardlautung für das Suffix „-ig“ den Ich-Laut [ɪç].

> fertig [ˈfɛrtɪç]
>
> lustig [ˈlʊstɪç]
>
> König [ˈkøːnɪç]

In Österreich, der Schweiz sowie einigen Teilen Süddeutschlands wird dagegen „-ig“ häufig allgemein als Verschlusslaut [ɪg] oder [ɪk] gesprochen.

Comment: Hörst Du irgendwo [ɪg]? Ich nicht.

Comment: Related: [Hat das Österreichische keine Auslautverhärtung?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/hat-das-%C3%96sterreichische-keine-auslautverh%C3%A4rtung)

Comment: Die Links geben bei mir komische Apache errors. Ist das bei anderen auch so, oder bin das nur ich?

Comment: Bei mir keine Apacheerrors, aber 404s.

Answer (score 5):

I actually learned in school that *Berg* is pronounced *Berch*. It's also *Hamburch* (or, rather, *Hambuäch*, if you're from Kiel, like me). *This is not true in standard German pronunciation, as teylyn explains.*

Because of the regional differences, you can basically use all variants, anyone will understand you. *-ig* will usually fade to *-ik*, though, because of the German *Auslautverhärtung*.

Comment: sorry, but that's simply wrong. `Berg` is not pronounced with a "ch" sound at the end. Auslautverhärtung is a phenomenon that applies to other contexts, for example `laufend` sounds like "laufent". But the correct pronunciation of the ending -ig is always /ɪç/ (as in mich), although in some regions it will be pronounced with a hard g or k ending.

Comment: +1.05 for "you can basically use all variants". -.05 for Berch. You don't even have mountains in Kiel!!1 ;)

Comment: @teylyn: That may be wrong, but is what I was taught in school, with this specific example. Sorry for that. With my Auslautverhärtungsbeispiel, I meant that when pronouncing the ending as g rather than ch, it fades to a hard k automatically. I did not mean that ch automatically fades to g or k.

Comment: @splattne: But there's the Bungsberg in Schleswig-Holstein, which actually has a ski lift. Yes, it's just 166m ;)

Comment: plus one for the reference to Auslautverhärtung! :)

Comment: Add *Hambuich* for my personal idiosyncrasy

Answer (score 5):

When 'g' forms part of an -ig suffix it is pronounced as -ich using the /ç/ phoneme.

> Eilig
>
> Traurig
>
> Honig

In some parts of Germany however, you may hear the consonant in an -ig suffix pronounced in a way that is closer to the /-ig/ phoneme.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia's [Standard German](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_German#Phonology) article says:

- /ɪʃ/ is used in western Germany
- /ɪk/ is used in southern Germany

Answer (score 4):

With adjectives, I was very specifically taught that without an ending, it's pronounced /ɪç/ (ie. fleißig), but when an ending is given, it changes to /ɪg/ (ie. der fleißige Student).

Edit: Should add, this is for standard Hochdeutsch.

Answer (score 3):

I listened to my old copy of "The Three-Penny Opera" and got the definite impression that the "isch" ending is sometimes voiced up to "izh". Lotte Lenya almost (but not quite) does it in "das Schiff mit acht Segeln und mit funfzizh Kanonen"; however, the amazing Willy Trenk-Trebitsch certainly does it in "Das Lied von der Unzulaenglichkeit":

"Den, fuer dieses Leben

Ist der Mensch nischt gut genug.

Darum hau ihn eben

Ruhizh auf den Hut."

(But maybe this is just a dramatic affectation. )

Comment: Careful with recordings from that era! At the time they still had some peculiar pronunciation habits that were necessary for public speakers with no (or later very poor) amplification systems, or for grammophone recordings. Nowadays they are no longer necessary to be understood, so they are no longer in common use. Not even among opera singers.

Comment: I love this discussion group.

Answer (score 1):

- /ɪʃ/ (as in Fisch)

This is common where people cannot speak the first variant (ɪç/ as in mich), for example in the Saarland and the palatinate.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly what other people have said.

*However* there is also the variant [iʒ], heard in the Rhine-Hessian region (Mainz, Alzey and others).

What was said about *Berg* **does** apply. The Rhine-Hessian region also pronounces that one as [bɛʒ] (the r almost unheard, the g turned into a French j). People from Hamburg often call their town [hamburç]. And some accents even ignore the 'turn to [ig] if there is an ending following' rule: in Franconian, *less* is pronounced [weniçɛ].

And, as a Bavarian and user of the [ik]-variant (which can also be called [ig]-variant), I have to correct taylyn in that **there is no single correct way** to pronounce those endings. Every one is equally valid.

So you see, anything goes ;)

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use /ɪç/ when talking with close friends or people who also speak my dialect. But the "correct" pronunciation my parents taught me is /ɪg/.

Comment: Solche Fragen sind keine Umfragen, bei denen jeder individuell seine Sprachpraxis öffentlich macht. Auch wenn es harsch klingt: Was Du persönlich treibst ist völlig uninteressant. Wenn Du jetzt AndreKRs Antwort um eine neue Variante ergänzt und dazugeschrieben hättest, wo diese gebräuchlich ist, wäre es etwas anderes. Auch wenn es ein Kommentar unter einer anderen Antwort gewesen wäre, hätte ich geschwiegen.

Answer (score -1):

There are some people like me how believed the simplifying lie

`Man schreibt es wie man es spricht`

told by their mother or some teachers, that things are spoken the same way as they are written.

I tend to to pronounce König like "König".