# What is the correct pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is the ending -ig pronounced, and where?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/683/how-is-the-ending-ig-pronounced-and-where)

My parents were from Vienna and for years I heard them pronounce words such as *zwanzig*, *fertig*, *notwendig* etc., by ending in "ich" rather than in "ick."

Most often nowadays, I hear "zwanzick", "fertick", "notwengick," rather than "zwanzich", "fertich" and "notwendich."

Can someone please explain the distinctions?

Comment: It's interesting that your parents spoke the "-ich" variant because most Austrians (I lived in Vienna a few years) pronounce it as "-ik". But there *are* some Viennese who speak are very "Hochdeutsch"-like German.