# What is the "correct" way of pronouncing - ig and the end of the word

Tags: pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is the ending -ig pronounced, and where?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/683/how-is-the-ending-ig-pronounced-and-where)

In all of my German books and several websites (as in [this one](http://joycep.myweb.port.ac.uk/pronounce/consong.html)), 
it is said that an -ig suffix it is pronounced as -ich using the /ç/. however when my German relative from Frankfurt pronounce the final g in those case as a /g/.

What is the better form to adapt to myself, or does it matter?

Comment: I would say the two common ways are like -k (zwanzik) or like -ch (zwanzich), in some region also -sch (zwanzisch)

Answer (score 4):

There are local differences. I grew up in Graz, Austria and live in Vienna, Austria since 1997. Here in Austria only actors in Burgtheater and german immigrants say

> Könich Ludwich ist nicht heilich.

(3 times with "~ich" at the end).

Austrian people say

> König Ludwig ist nicht heilig.

(3 times with "~ig").

Comment: If we talk about *König Ludwig* (I. or II.) then we have to keep in mind that he was Bavarian. Therefore in **any case** *Ludwig* is pronounced **ˈluːdvɪk**. This can also be seen in towns named after him: *Ludwigshafen*, *Ludwigsburg* where the -ig is always pronounced **ik**.

Comment: Generell wird -ig `ɪk`betont. Und das auch in Berlin :)

Comment: Actually, in this case "König" is pronounced "Kini", so no "ig" at all :-)

Comment: @Landei: Please do not confuse non-native spreakers. "Kini" in bavarian dialect, not standard-german.