# Does German phonetics fully determine the spelling?

Tags: pronunciation, accent

It is clear that there are different, equally valid ways to read a word in German (e.g. alveolar or uvular `r`, etc.) How true is the converse statement: *phonetics fully determine the spelling*? I'm specifically interested in the influence that different German accents might have on the spelling. For instance, is there a German accent by which phonemes are *omitted*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Phonetics do not fully determine the spelling in German. For instance, terminal devoicing is not reflected in the orthography ("Wand" = [vant]), and vowel length can be indicated in several ways ("e" in "Weg", "ee" in "See", and "eh" in "Mehl" represent the same vowel [eː]).

There are some phonemes that are omitted very frequently. The most important case is probably [ə] in final syllables. For example "reden" = [ˈʁeːdən] usually becomes [ˈʁeːdn], "haben" = [ˈhaːbən] becomes [ˈhaːbm] or colloquially even [ham]. Coming from the Ruhr area, I'd pronounce a phrase like "das haben wir nicht" as [dasˈhamvənɪç]. In the Swabian dialect, initial "ge" becomes "k", so "gesund" [gəˈzʊnt] is pronounced as [ksʊnt].

Comment: There are many examples of homophones that are spelled differently, such as _See_ and _seh_, _Leute_ and _läute_, _Rad_ and _Rat_, _Lerche_ and _Lärche_ etc.

Comment: An example for same spelling, but different phonetic: Weg/weg „Ich ging auf demselben Weg weg, auf dem ich hergekommen war.“

Answer (score 8):

There are four main reasons why the spelling of a German word might deviate from the phonetic spelling (which is rather complicated itself, especially concerning the indication of the length of vowels):

- Loanwords and proper names, even if they are hardly perceived as such anymore. Either they are pronounced different like *Maschine* (the phonetic spelling would be *Maschiene*), or they are not covered by phonetic spelling, like *Motiv* or *egal.*
- Consistency over inflections of the word. E.g., apart from the initial consonant, *Wald* and *Halt* are pronounced identically due to terminal devoicing (Auslautverhärtung), but if inflected the last letter is pronounced differently (Wälder vs. Halte). In another example, *Wälder* and *Gelder* are pronounced identically (apart from the initial consonant), but are inflections of differently pronounced words (Wald, Geld).
- Avoiding that two phonetically identical words are spelled identically, e.g., Waagen vs. Wagen, seit vs. seid, dass vs. das.
- Composites words, who are pronounced differently than a simple composition of their parts, e.g., [*vierzehn*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/why-are-vier-and-the-beginning-of-vierzehn-not-pronounced-the-same)*, fünffach.*

A longer description with more examples can be found in the preface to the [official spelling rules](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, useful information. +1 Maybe I didn't reflected in the question's title what I am really after, so is my fault, but I was really interested in the accents.