# About the -er pronunciation in German

Tags: pronunciation

Ok, so I understand -er is almost always pronounced as a shwa or "uh". Often it goes all the way to an "ah" sound in German in my experience.
Non-native speakers of German that come from rhotic languages (fellow Slavic speakers notably) often make the mistake of pronouncing **Fischer** as fish-eh-r (or fish-air with short "ai" and rhotic "r") while Germans will be like "fish-ah"/"fish-uh".

1. My first question is how is this different than the EN speakers dropping the final -r? To me it's very similar to how some British speakers drop the last -r. How did it develop? Was it always like that, or were medieval Germans prone to say Fish-ehr? Which Germanic languages would pronounce the -er clearly today? I thought the name of a character in a sitcom was Peggy Wanka (that's how it was dubbed in Bulgarian, overcorrection?). Turns out it's actually, well, Wank*er*. :D
2. I wonder if Germans are able to hear the difference between, say Joschk**a** and Joschk**er**? Wouldn't they be pronounced vaguely the same? In German I always hear the name of a politician  pronounced as Joschka Fisha while in my native Bulgarian it has always been Joschka Fish-ehr/Fish-air with hard r and short eh in "ai".

Comment: Link: I'm pretty sure the Peggy character being referred to is [Peg Bundy née Wanker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Married..._with_Children_characters#Peg_Bundy) from "Married... with Children". "Wanker" isn't common in American slang, so the humor of Al referring to his in-laws as "the Wankers" is a bit more subtle in the US than it would be England; In England I think it would be too obvious to be very funny.

Comment: It is a bit unfortunate that this is two questions in one, because I too would be interested in an answer to (1), and I fear that we will not get one.

Comment: To clarify. *-ka* is a very frequent ending in Slavic names. Misunderstanding *-k-er* from cross-interfering native language habits should be, after all, understandable.

Answer (score 3):

In [my question about German vowels](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/34755/1487) (asked in German language) I gave examples for all the 30 different vowels in Germans words that I am aware of. Note, that long and short vowels of the same quality are counted as distinct vowels (because for example the pair *»Stahl« - »Stall«* can be distinguished only by the length of the vowel), and I also counted stressed and unstressed vowels as two different vowels because stress is the only difference between the two version of *»umgehen«* in *»Er versucht die Sperre zu **umgehen**«* and *»Ich kann mit dieser Schuld nicht **umgehen**.«*

Two of these 30 vowels are important for your question, because they are different than the 28 other vowels:

- [ə] last sound in the word *»Blum**e**«* ("flower")
- [ɐ] last sound in the word *»Brud**er**«* ("brother")

Next thing you should know:

When talking about stress of syllables there are three different types of syllables in German words:

- stressed syllables (example: 2<sup>nd</sup> syllable of *»ent**ste**hen«*)
- unstressed syllables (example: 1<sup>st</sup> syllable of *»**ent**stehen«*)
- reduction syllables (example: 3<sup>rd</sup> syllable of *»entsteh**en**«*)

Reduction syllables are even less stressed than unstressed syllables, and they only can appear at the end of a word. (Well, in compound words they also can appear in the middle of the compound word, but even there, only at the end of an "atomic" word like the syllable *»er«* in *»Jedermann«*.)

A German reduction syllable always contains the letter *»e«* in its written form, but when you pronounce it, only the vowels [ə] or [ɐ] can appear. Never ever can a German reduction syllable have another spoken vowel. They just can have no vowel at all.

- Syllables that are spoken with [ə] (German name: [Schwa](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa), English name: [schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa))

  > -e: jed**e** [ˈjeːd**ə**]
  > -em: jed**e**m [ˈjeːd**ə**m]
  > -es: jed**e**s [ˈjeːd**ə**s]
  > -est: zumind**e**st [t͡suˈmɪnd**ə**st]
- Syllables that are spoken with [ɐ] (German name: »Tiefschwa« or [Fast offener Zentralvokal](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_offener_Zentralvokal), English name: [near-open central vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-open_central_vowel))

  > -er: jed**er** [ˈjeːd**ɐ**]
  > -ern: ford**er**n [ˈfɔʁd**ɐ**n]
  > -ert: hund**er**t [ˈhʊnd**ɐ**t]
  > -erst: äuß**er**st [ˈɔɪ̯s**ɐ**st]
- Syllables that are spoken without any vowel but with a vocalized sonor consonant

  > -en: jeden [ˈjeːdn̩] (vocalized N instead of a vowel)
  > -el: Regel [ˈʁeːɡl̩] (vocalized L instead of a vowel)
  > -eln: kitzeln [ˈkɪt͡sl̩n] (vocalized L instead of a vowel)
  > -elt: kitzelt [ˈkɪt͡sl̩t] (vocalized L instead of a vowel)
  > -elst: kitzelst [ˈkɪt͡sl̩st] (vocalized L instead of a vowel)

Neither [ə] nor [ɐ] can appear in a "normal" i.e. non-reduction syllable, and as the pair *»jede - jeder«* ([ˈjeːdə] - [ˈjeːdɐ]) demonstrates, they also must not be mixed up.

---

When a German word in it's written form ends in a syllable that does not contain the letter *»e«,* then this word can not be pronounced with [ə] or [ɐ].

The pair *Joschka - Joschker* is not a good example, because the word *»Joschker«* doesn't exist, so there is no defined pronunciation for it. But I have another pair for you:

- **Anka** (female first name from Bulgarian and Serbian language)
  Pronunciation: [ˈaŋka] (first and second vowel differ only in the amount of stress, but are of the same quality)
- **Anker** (English; anchor, keeper)
  Pronunciation: [ˈaŋkɐ] (first and second syllable are two differnt sounds)

another pair (although the first syllable has vowels of different lengths):

- **meta** (bound lexeme like in **Meta**physik) (same word as in English)
  Pronunciation: [ˈmeta]
- **Meter** (physical unit, same as in English)
  Pronunciation: [ˈmeːtɐ]

---

### What is the difference between [a] and [ɐ]?

- [a] [open front unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_front_unrounded_vowel)
  in German: [Ungerundeter offener Vorderzungenvokal](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungerundeter_offener_Vorderzungenvokal) = unropundes open front-tounge vowel
  You speak this sound with lips that are not rounded but stretched from left to right and you produce the sound in the front part of your mouth
- [ɐ] [near-open central vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-open_central_vowel)
  in German: [fast offener Zentralvokal](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_offener_Zentralvokal) = almost open central vowel
  You speak this sound with a mouth that is more open that at many other vowels, and you produce the sound in the middle of your mouth

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to confirm what @RDBury also wrote: <a> and <-er> are usually realised by two different vowels in German.

- <a> relates to [[a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_central_unrounded_vowel)] or [​aː]
- <-er> relates to [[ɐ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-open_central_vowel)] (sometimes called ***Tief**schwa* 'low schwa' or *a-Schwa*): lower and more central than [a]

So at least when spoken carefully, it is possible to distinguish *Joschka* from *Joschker*, as well as *Opa* from *Oper* and *Klara* from *klarer*. However, it is possible that speakers mumble to the extent where the sounds become very similiar, e.g. intentionally in the pun name *Klara Fall* (resembling *klarer Fall* 'clear case').

**Difference to English:** As @RDBury explains, a RP speaker would pronounce *großer* like *große*, while in German the two are pronounced different: [ˈɡʁoːsɐ] vs. [ˈɡʁoːsə], because:

- Unstressed short <e> relates to [ə], the proper schwa (or *e-Schwa*)

So *Tiefschwa* [ɐ] and *(e-)Schwa* [ə] need to be distinguished from each other as well.

Comment: I agree in general, except that "[it is possible to distinguish] Opa from Oper". Hard disagree on lexical grounds! I rely chiefly on DPs with gendered determiners for this one and let context do the heavy lifting. *Opa* is in fact a determinet (if used like a pornoun). The lexems are far from minimally distant, one a nursery word, the other a high brow loan from Italian *opera* (where the Ablaut is liable to decline as seen in *operette*, *opus*, see also *O.P.* /'o.pe:/,  *ora, labora*, *prét*). After all, only ancient people go the opera, so the homonyme is fully justified.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a native speaker, so I'm only going by IPA notations, various sound files (for example in Wiktionary), and speech to text programs (for example in Google translate and dict.cc). A native speaker might be able to fill in more detail. Wiktionary gives the IPA symbol /ɐ/ to the final *-er* sound in German, while it gives the final "-er" sound in an English accent (RP) as /ə/. To my (American) ears the nonrhotic "-er" is a bit more open than the "o" in unstressed "of", which is also represented as /ə/ in IPA, but perhaps that's just me. The *a* in *etwa* is given the IPA symbol /a/ which is not the same as /ɐ/. Wiktionary also gives the /ə/ symbol to the final *-e* in *Tasche*, though to my ears there's a shade more "e-ness" to the sound than the "o" in unstressed "of". So, at least according to IPA notations, the final *-er*, final *-e*, and final *-a* are all different in German; how they compare with the British "-er" or American schwa is debatable (in my opinion).

In any case, all these sounds are unstressed and presumably sound more similar when spoken quickly. I think there's also a tendency for differences to be heard when not spoken. A German speaker expects to hear *-er* at the end of *der Fisch-* and *-e* at the end of *die Fisch-*, so they will usually hear that regardless of which one is actually spoken. My understanding is that the American accent is rather notorious for this phenomenon, though as an American I don't really notice it myself.

Answer (score 0):

How it came to be:
The "weakening" (replacement with some kind of weak vocal or Schwa sound  conserved in orthography as *e*, then complete annihilation in prononciation) of the vocals in the terminating syllabes was probably a long term effect of the initial stress of proto germanic. This effect continued with the terminating consonant *-r* and produced some kind of *a* or a-Schwa sound instead of *-er*.

In German, the precise sound **actually** spoken depends on the region/dialect and on the situation: In formal speech, people tend to over-correct prononciation, for example *'bru:der* (Bruder, engl. brother). But in an informal conversation they will say *'bru:dɐ* where the dialects do have the respective Schwa-sound. For example in Austria, speakers will use a weakly spoken *a* instead of the ɐ-Schwa, as the dialects there do not have Schwa-sounds.

To further illustrate the latter: Some time ago, there was an advertisement for pudding from a german company on austrian TV. It was targeted towards children and contained a rhyme like "Die [Kuh] Paula mit der Brille..." ("the [cow] Paula with glasses..."). The word Brille (glasses) was prononced the "german" way, that is, with an e-Schwa, but for austrian ears this sounded like "Brillö", and kids were "amused" by the strange prononciation.