# Sind Unterschiede in der Aussprache des letzten Lautes in „Honig“ und „Teig“ regional bedingt?

Tags: pronunciation, regional

In meiner Familie, die aus ziemlich unterschiedlichen Regionen kommt (Niederrhein, Thüringen, Oberschlesien) wurde „Honig“ von allen stets `-ç`, aber „Teig“ immer `-k` ausgesprochen. Man kann aber anscheinend in egal welcher Gegend Menschen begegnen, die das eine oder das andere exakt gegensätzlich aussprechen würden.

Gibt es Regionen, in denen das herkömmlicherweise so gemacht wird? Und wie heißt der linguistische Vorgang, der hier am Werk ist?

Comment: Related: [How is the ending -ig pronounced, and where?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/683/9551)

Comment: Interessant! Hier im Schwabenland erinnere ich mich, dass wir immer Teik und Honik, aber dann Honichbrot gesagt haben. Ob es da eine Systematik gibt, ist mir aber unklar.

Comment: Ist eigentlich keine Dublette, da 1. verschiedene Sprachen und 2. kein _Teig_ in der anderen Frage.

Comment: @chirlu In einigen Antworten wird auf Niederrheinisch und Hamburgisch verwiesen, *Berch* und *Hamburch* schienen mir nah genug dran zu sein... musste aber auch etwas suchen