# How do you pronounce the "g" in "Heiligtum"?

Tags: pronunciation

In the Ode to Joy lyrics, the phrase "Himmlische, dein Heiligtum" appears early on. When I listen to the musical setting, in Beethoven's 9th, it is hard for me to discern from the voice of the tenor whether the "g" gets devoiced into a "k". This brings me to the question. In a performance of Beethoven's 9th, particularly the ode in the final movement, how should "Heiligtum" be pronounced? Does the "g" get pronounced like a "k" as in Ta**g**? I would expect this because the "g" comes at the end of a syllable (or so I think), and it's my understanding that devoicing happens at the end of a syllable as well as the end of a word.

Now, I know that there are regional differences in regard to pronunciation, but I assume that the vocalists follow some sort of standard.

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/683/how-is-the-ending-ig-pronounced-and-where/4337#4337

Comment: The standard pronunciation is *-ich* as in *ich*.

Comment: It depends on dialect. In Austria and other Bavarian dialects, it is harder than "g" but softer than "k", this is called "Ablautverhärtung". And no, it is not like *ich*.

Comment: @rexkogitans, I should have written “German standard pronunciation”. Regional differences have been addressed in the question that I have linked.

Comment: Anything in the general area between *g*, *k* and *ch* (as in *ich*), but excepting hard *k* itself, is a perfectly normal, natural, native speaker pronunciation. Though professional speakers in German national media use *ch* and those in the south are more likely to use something close to *g*, none of these pronunciations is ever wrong. (*K* itself and *sch* also occur in some reasons, but are non-standard or dialectal, hence not appropriate in the context of the question.) And yes, this question is a duplicate of one that already has an excellent answer.

Comment: Eben gefunden, 3 Arten in Köln ein G auszusprechen: Fluchzeuschträjer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[ç], see [Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/zweifelsfaelle-bei-der-aussprache) as reference. The stage pronounciation rules also leave no other choice. In normal talk I decidedly assume regional variations. Especially for religious terms there seems to be an additional urge, to pronounce them unsloppy (similar to Tag) as incorrect as this may be.

Comment: This is currently a link only answer. You should say what the Duden recommends.

Answer (score 15):

It depends on the region. There are two main variations.

1. The "normal"* pronunciation would be like in 'gerne' (or like you would pronounce the 'ck' in the English word 'lick').
2. However, in some regions it's pronounced soft like the 'ch' in 'dich'.

*normal, because it follows the default, distinct pronunciation for 'g', whereas (2) makes the 'g' sound like a 'ch', i.e., would mean this is an exception.

From the link guidot points out in his answer, I'd assume the 'officially' (Duden) correct way would be (1) as well, but the rule can also be interpreted in favour of (2).

From the Duden page that guidot linked (http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/zweifelsfaelle-bei-der-aussprache): 
"Dasselbe gilt auch für die Buchstabenfolge -ig: Auch hier wird das auslautende -g standardsprachlich nicht wie ein k [k] gesprochen, sondern wie der Reibelaut in dem Wort „ich". Das gilt für Wörter wie König, Honig, eilig, sperrig und viele andere Adjektive auf -ig. *Sobald aber durch Deklination weitere Buchstaben hinzutreten, wird das g wieder wie g gesprochen: die Könige, eilige Nachrichten, in einer sperrigen Kiste.* Folgt der Endung -ig die Ableitungssilbe -lich (königlich), so wird das g wie ein k [k] gesprochen."

Basically the official rule says: a) In cases of '-ig' at the end of word (like in "heilig") the 'g' is pronounced like a 'ch'. b) If additional  letters are added by declination after the 'ig', like in "Könige", the 'g' is spoken like any other 'g', i.e. a little softer than a 'k'. c) If, however, the 'ig' is followed by a 'lich', like in "königlich" the 'g' is pronounced strong like a 'k'.

So in the case of "Heiligtum" *I think* b) should apply, whereas I ignore that the rule says "if *by declination* additional letters follow the 'ig'", so one might argue that b) shouldn't apply to "Heiligtum" as the 'tum' part is a suffix not a declination. One might then either argue that the rule does not apply at all, which would mean the normal 'g' pronunciation applies as well. Or one could argue that a) applies to 'Heilig' and its spoken the same if it occurs in a compound word/form.

All in all, I'd say there is about an equally good case to use both, in some region you might get some strange looks with either version. And as the discussions here show, common usage as well as official rule interpretation are debatable even amongst native speakers.

When singing, I'd say, use whichever version of the two that goes better to your melody ;)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63516/discussion-on-answer-by-darkwing-how-do-you-pronounce-the-g-in-heiligtum).

Answer (score 12):

It's ç and the whole word is [ˈhaɪ̯lɪçtuːm].

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but is that the same as -ch?

Comment: With some lack of precision in the answer: yes, it is "ch". But mind that there are two ways of pronouncing "ch": the one like in *Dach*, the other like in *dich*. In *Heiligtum* it is like in *dich*. If you pronounce it like in *Dach* you sound like a Russian.

Comment: -1, because there is no reference

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Depends where you live. For me it a simple "g" like in "gerne". If you go like that, you would pronounce "Flugzeug" "Fluchzeuch". As said, depends in which region you are.

Comment: @Cataklysim Genau. Die wo aus Hambuich kommet mögen es so sagen, aber mir hier unten saget ein "g" wo ein "g" ist.

Comment: @Cataklysim The answer gives the correct pronunciation for Hochdeutsch. Regional variants do exist of course, but then the same is true for almost every word.

Answer (score 11):

The existing answers seem to focus on the *spoken* pronunciation.

However, professional singers may vocalise words differently to increase intelligibility of words when singing (source: [German Wikipedia entry](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussprache_der_deutschen_Sprache#Deutsche_Aussprache_im_klassischen_Gesang)).

[This German website](http://www.singen-und-stimme.de/2008/05/27/aussprache-beim-chorsingen/) gives a little summary of the rules.
Among others, there is the rule

> „ch“ wird gesprochen in der Endung -ig im Silbenschluß vor Konsonanten: ewig, befriedigt, freudigste.

which roughly translates to:

> If a syllable ends with the ending *-ig* and is followed by a consonant, it is pronounded as "ch", examples are *ewig, befriedigt, freudigste*

Addendum by me:

- Due to the proceeding *i*, it is the *ch* as in *ich*

Applying this rule, *Heiligtum* includes the *-ig* followed by a consonant and therefore should be pronounced with [ç].

On the other hand, in "Stille Nacht, heilige Nacht", the *-ig* in *heilige* is followed by a vowel and would be pronounced as [g].

When looking for a good English reference, I found [this](http://dulwichchoralsociety.org.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/German-pronunciation-for-singers.pdf), which is incomplete regarding the *-ig followed by consonant* cases like *Heiligtum*, but lists the exception, that the *-ig* might be followed by an *-lich*, as in *königlich*, where you would pronounce the g as [k].

Since it is a complex topic, there are books written about pronunciation for singers :)

Comment: In "königlich", it would be pronounced like the "g" in "Tag", wouldn't it, not like the "g" in "Tage" or "könige"? That is, the rule for "-ig" is to have Auslautverhärtung, but not spirantization before "-lich" in "official"/standard/reference German (I don't know anything about German regional languages, so I will stay silent about them), making the sound approach [k], so it seems a bit misleading to just write [g].

Comment: @sumelic I guess I was mislead by my own way of speaking'/dialect, where a [k] in königlich would sound a bit exaggerated :) I have edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Well, all the people I know pronouce the `g` like in *Tag*.

Comment: And how do they pronounce it in _Tag_?

Comment: never heard it like `Tag`. ç example for you: https://youtu.be/sJQ32q2k8Uo?t=56m6s

Comment: @Eller: Well, like in *genau* or *gerne*.

Comment: @oliholz: Wenn ich suche, finde ich bestimmt auch ein Beispiel, wo es hinten mit "k" gesprochen wird.

Comment: Natürlich gibt es regionale Unterschiede, das wurde schon ausreichend bei anderen Fragen besprochen.

Comment: Ja, regionale Unterschiede in der Umgangssprache. Aber die "Ode an die Freude" hat sicherlich ein Konsens unter Experten im klassischem Gesang, wie es ursprünglich ausgesprochen wurde. Habe mir jetzt die größten 15 Künstler und Philharmoniker die ich finden konnte angehört. Würde gerne ein Gegenbeispiel hören. @Thorsten Dittmar